# Pass method's parameters to another method within?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, parameters, arguments

I have the following code:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    someMethod(sameParameters);
}
```

How do I do this? Can you provide an example?

Comment: what exactly is your problem? what have you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not what you wanted but this is how:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    someMethod(sender, cmd, commandLabel, args);
}
```

Comment: There isn't a better way, OP.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way to do this is to simply pass all received parameters as arguments. That is,

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    someMethod(sender, cmd, commandLabel, args);
}
```

Comment: +1 That is the obvious way, and unless the OP provides more background, there is no obvious problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

**A [variadic<sup>Wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.23.2C_C.2B.2B.2FCLI.2C_VB.net.2C_and_Java) approach might look nicer:**

```
void foo(Object... params) {
    // access like params[0], for example
    delegateFoo(params);
}

void delegateFoo(Object... params) {
    // params[0] is same as above
}
```